C/C++ mode aggresive auto indent
In the C/C++ mode, on some contexts, like when pressing enter at the end of a function declaration, code is aggressively indented backwards with a style that ignores my overall configuration.
For example:
void some_function_that_is_very_wide(int arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3, int arg4, int arg5, int arg6/*CURSOR*/);

When pressing RET on /*CURSOR*/, it is formatted like so:
void some_function_that_is_very_wide(int arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3,
                                     int arg4, int arg5,
                                     int arg6
                                         );

Even though if I select the region and press TAB, it formats differently, like so:
void some_function_that_is_very_wide(int arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3,
                                     int arg4, int arg5,
                                     int arg6
);

Iv'e checked the binding, and it says newline-and-indent, with some information about :around advice: being used.
Is there some simple way for me to disable this?
The relevant configuration for this layer is:
(defun dotspacemacs/layers ()
  (setq-default
   ;; ...
   dotspacemacs-configuration-layers
   '(
     (lsp :variables
          lsp-lens-enable t
          lsp-rust-server 'rust-analyzer
          lsp-rust-analyzer-server-display-inlay-hints t
          lsp-rust-analyzer-check-all-targets nil
          ;; lsp-rust-analyzer-expand-macro t

          lsp-ui-doc-enable t
          lsp-ui-sideline-show-hover nil
          )
     (c-c++ :variables
            ;; c-c++-backend 'lsp-ccls
            lsp-enable-file-watchers nil
            lsp-enable-indentation nil
            c-c++-backend 'lsp-clangd
            c-c++-enable-clang-format-on-save nil
            c-c++/init-clang-format nil
            c-c++/pre-init-clang-format nil
            c-c++/post-init-clang-format nil
            c-c++-adopt-subprojects t
            c-c++-default-mode-for-headers 'c++-mode
            c-c++-enable-google-style nil
            c-c++-enable-google-newline nil
            c-c++-enable-auto-newline nil
            c-c++-adopt-subprojects t
            )
     )
   )
  )

(defun dotspacemacs/user-config ()
  (add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook
            (lambda ()
              (setq c-syntactic-indentation t
                    tab-width 4
                    c-default-style "linux"
                    c-basic-offset 4
                    c-tab-always-indent t
                    indent-tabs-mode nil
                    hide-ifdef-shadow t
                    ;; comment-start "// "
                    ;; commend-end ""
                    )
              (c-set-offset 'arglist-intro '+)
              (c-set-offset 'arglist-close 0)
              (hide-ifdef-mode)
              (flyspell-mode-off)
              (evil-close-folds)
              (auto-fill-mode)
              (hide-ifdefs)
              (platformio-conditionally-enable)
              (add-hook 'after-save-hook (lambda () (hide-ifdefs)))
              (define-key c-mode-map (kbd "C-<return>") 'luctins/cc-mode-continue-comment)
              )
            )
  )

I'm using spacemacs develop, on emacs 29.3.
update:
I've tried disabling electric-indent-mode and aggresive-indent-mode and the result is the same.
Also of note is:
even something like this:
void some_function_that_is_very_wide(
    int arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3,
    int arg4, int arg5,
    int arg6/*CURSOR*/);

is auto formatted to this:
void some_function_that_is_very_wide(int arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3,
                                     int arg4, int arg5,
                                     int arg6
                                         );

When RET is pressed at /*CURSOR*/.
After a disabling a few modes it seems lsp-managed-mode was the culprit, but I don't know from where it gets this configuration.

For listing all active modes press [C-h m]. Ensure, that these modes are disabled:

Aggressive-Indent (local and global);
Electric-Indent (local and global).

Turn off this modes and check Emacs behavior. Then update settings in your init.el.
Also, using some global modes is not a good idea.

Sadly even with both modes the result is the same. Maybe this behavior has something to do with the syntatic context being different before (arglist-cont-nonempty) and after (arglist-close) pressing RET? also this seems to happen regardless of lsp used (CCLS and Clangd).
